# Jersey 1.x is interpreting my serialized null fields as Strings with the value of "null". How do I prevent this?

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jackson

This is a very nasty bug.  Here's what's happening:  When I run client to server tests, my tests all work.  When I query a linux server with the same source code, it fails.

It only occurs on linux (perhaps macs, I haven't checked).  I'm on Windows 7 and can't reproduce this.  But, *this may be an red herring*.  Another difference is that I'm running off of an exploded ear and the failing servers are running off of a packaged ear.  If this is the culprit, it probably is a classpath issue.

This has to do with the server.  If I change *my* client code to call a linux server, it will fail.  To me that rules out the client's responsibility.

I've set a break point on the servers to compare the input and to my surprise the content of the entity looks very different.  My working server makes the object look like this:

[image]

When I set the breakpoint on the linux server, it looks like this:

[image]

Notice how the second one is full of strings with the value of "null" and empty objects.  What could be causing this?  I'm using Jersey 1.x and Jackson 2.0 and JAXB.  But this is a huge project that may have older versions of those jars in the classpath.  I'm not even sure where to suspect this error could be coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the cause of this was in fact a classpath issue.  I was using a different install of glassfish compared to everyone else.  Everyone else's glassfish had extra libs under "glassfish/lib":

```
jackson-asl-0.9.4.jar
jersey-bundle-1.0.3.1.jar
jsr311-api-1.0.jar
```

Once I removed these 3 libs, my code worked consistently everywhere.  I removed all 3 at once, so I'm not sure if they are all necessary to remove.  But *at least* one of these jars was responsible.